# jQuery: Simple Fade buttons from one class to another?

Tags: jquery, fade

I've been searching everywhere for this, hope some of you experts can help me out, as i'm am finding it difficult, i've been searching how to do this, but only finding actual direct colour, opacity or image swapping fade tutorials..... but no actual how to fade one class to another class on hover...

For example:

Button has .btn class....

Rollover, it becomes:

.btnhover

But I would like it to have a nice gentle fade to the new class, not just swap (As that can easily be done in just css)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI has a `toggleClass` method which can be used to animate from `class A` to `class B`.

```
toggleClass( class, [duration] )
```

> Adds the specified class if it is not
>   present, and removes the specified
>   class if it is present, using an
>   optional transition.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called **transition**, meaning that going from one **state** to another state smoothly and over time, not abruptly and sudden. As an alternative, I suggest using CSS3 Transitions, or jQuery `animate` function. Please let me know if those alternatives can satisfy your requirements.

Update:
jQuery itself doesn't have this capability. But jQueryUI extends jQuery's animate method such that you can apply transition from one CSS class to another CSS class smoothly. 
[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/) is where you can find it.

Update:

```
var button = $('#button');
button.hover(function(){
   button.switchClass('ordinary', 'hovered', 1000);       
}, function(){
   button.switchClass('hovered', 'ordinary', 1000); 
});
```

Comment: Hi,I would definitely like to use jquery, but need a working example please if possible?

Comment: I see, ok... that makes sense, but..lol (sorry) - What is I wanted to add the :hover class e.g.    .btn > .btn:hover ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `animate()` - you need to use jquery API to be able to use this function. Pretty simple - just animate the properties of the class you want to change on hover.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

I think the Jquery UI plugin allows for animation between classes. It might be worth checking that out:

[Jquery UI Animate](http://jqueryui.com/docs/toggleClass)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex is the class (if it has images in the background, different font types, etc..) I think a way you can achieve this effect is by  duplicating the element, leaving one hidden and then use the fadeIn and fadeOut effects.

This could be an example:

```
<div id="button">
  <div class="normal"> 
     Your element 
  </div>
  <div class="hover" style="display:none;"> 
     Your element while hovering
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#button").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#button.normal").fadeOut();    
    $("#button.hover").fadeIn();

}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("#button.normal").fadeIn();    
    $("#button.hover").fadeOut();

});

</script>
```

Comment: Actually..i don't want 2 identical lements on the page, I just want to switch classes...

Comment: depending how complex are the classes (images in the background, different font types,different sizes) and if you want a smooth transition this could be a good option although having duplicated elements its not a good practice

Comment: It's for a Navigation so i don't want the LI repeating twice, I just want to switch class on 1 element

Comment: then use jQueryUI and toggleClass()